# DeviceIoControl with DWORD

Tags: c++, deviceiocontrol

My OS is Win7 64bit. I'm trying to pass the value of a variable, not the address of it (process id, DWORD) via DeviceIoControl to my driver. I have tried it several times, but only got bluescreens or the error code of 998.

On usermode side, I make sure that hDevice is valid, the CTL_CODE looks like this:

```
#define SENDPID CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0x808, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA)
```

Then I'm doing this:

```
DWORD pID = FindProcessName("someprocess.exe");
if (!pID) return false;
if (!DeviceIoControl(hDevice, SENDPID, &pID, sizeof(pID), NULL, 0, &BytesIO, 0))
{
    cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    return false;
}
```

and on Kernelmode (DriverEntry):

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT Object, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
UNICODE_STRING dNUS = { 0 };
RtlInitUnicodeString(&dNUS, L"\\Device\\testdriver");

UNICODE_STRING dSLU = { 0 };
RtlInitUnicodeString(&dSLU, L"\\DosDevices\\testdriver");

IoCreateDevice(Object, 0, &dNUS, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &deviceObj);
IoCreateSymbolicLink(&dSLU, &dNUS);

Object->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = CCreate;
Object->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = CClose;
Object->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = IOCTL;
Object->DriverUnload = Unload;

return(STATUS_SUCCESS);
}
```

and my IOCTL function:

```
NTSTATUS IOCTL(PDEVICE_OBJECT Object, PIRP IRP)
{
PIO_STACK_LOCATION StackLocation = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(IRP);
size_t size = 0;
DWORD pID = 0;

if (StackLocation->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode == SENDPID)
{
    pID = IRP->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
    size = sizeof(pID);
}

IRP->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
IRP->IoStatus.Information = size;
IofCompleteRequest(IRP, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
return(STATUS_SUCCESS);
}
```

If anyone could tell me what to change, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the app side, why is `FindProcessName()` returning a `DWORD*` pointer instead of a `DWORD` value?  Or, does it really return a `DWORD` value and you are just erroneously type-casting it to a `DWORD*` pointer?

By defining `pID` as a `DWORD*` pointer, `sizeof(pID)` is the wrong value to pass to `DeviceIoControl()`.  It is passing the size of the pointer itself (4 on 32bit, 8 on 64bit), not the size of the `DWORD` value being pointed at (`sizeof(DWORD)` is always 4).

If `pID` is a real pointer to a `DWORD` in memory, you would need to use `sizeof(*pID)` instead of `sizeof(pID)`.  But what if `FindProcessName()` returns 0?  Then you would end up passing a NULL pointer to `DeviceIoControl()`, even though you are telling `DeviceIoControl()` that you are passing it 4 bytes.

You should change `FindProcessName()` to return a `DWORD` value (if it not already) instead of a `DWORD*` pointer, and then use the `&` operator to pass the address of that `DWORD` to `DeviceIoControl()`, eg:

```
DWORD pID = FindProcessName("DayZ.exe");
if (!DeviceIoControl(hDevice, SENDPID, &pID, sizeof(pID), NULL, 0, &BytesIO, 0))
```

Then on the kernel side, just type-cast the `SystemBuffer` to access the value (after validating that the `SystemBuffer` contains at least 4 bytes, of course):

```
NTSTATUS IOCTL(PDEVICE_OBJECT Object, PIRP IRP)
{
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION StackLocation = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(IRP);
    size_t size = 0;
    DWORD pID = 0;

    if ((StackLocation->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode == SENDPID) &&
        (StackLocation->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength >= sizeof(pID)))
    {
        pID = *(DWORD*)(IRP->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer);
        size = sizeof(pID);
    }

    IRP->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    IRP->IoStatus.Information = size;
    IofCompleteRequest(IRP, IO_NO_INCREMENT);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advanced answer. FindProcessName is actually returning a DWORD. Since I have been looking around, I think I have already tried your Version and BOSD'd, but I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Then you are likely not processing the IRP buffer correctly.  Please [edit] your question to show your actual driver code that handles `SENDPID`.

Comment: @MarcelMar: you altered your app code to define `pID` as a `DWORD` (good), but you are passing it **by value** to the `lpInBuffer` parameter of `DeviceIoControl()`, which will not compile as that parameter is expecting a `void*` pointer instead.  You need to pass `&pID` instead.  Also, your app code is using `SENDPID`, but your driver code is looking for `PUSHPID` instead, which is expecting a pointer to an `IDCONTAINER` struct instead of a `DWORD`. What is `IDCONTAINER` defined as? And why are you using `PUSHPID` instead of `SENDPID`?

Comment: oops, sorry, I was trying stuff out and messed up copy & pasting, this is the code that is up to date right now.

Comment: @MarcelMar: Now the passing of `pID` looks OK.  But your use of `SystemBuffer` is wrong.  As I stated in my answer, your driver code needs to use `pID = *(DWORD*)(IRP->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer);` instead.

Comment: For some reason, even with your edited code, I can't seem to send the pID correctly. I think that `*(DWORD*)` is not correct, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Then you need to actually **debug your code** and find out what is really happening.  StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about that. I'll let everyone know once I managed to find the problem.

Comment: Wow.. I have been using DbgPrint and tried to print the value of pID. It didn't print anything, so I assumed that the value is just invalid. To my surprise it's actually valid. Thanks for helping me :)